# Debian Server Backup in Realtime - Mail, Apache, MySQL

Tags: linux, debian, backup

I'm looking for a backup strategy for my production server. It should be fully automatic and as "real-time" as possible.

Further, i don't want to do much to recover everything. Let's say like a backup server which we can switch to if the production server goes down.

I'm using the following services with Debian Lenny:

- Apache2
- MySQL 5.1
- Postfix
- Dovecot
- SpamAssassin
- SSH of course

So, i think i'll need a backup-server which replicates all files in near-real-time. Is this a well-known scenario? Can you tell me what i have to do to achieve this?

Further, i think i'll need Full- and incremental Backups of the System (each week Full and every 12 Hours incremental). How can i achieve this ?

This all should be easy and fast to recover ... Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

I don't use Plesk.

Comment: Please complete your question with at least the amount of data you need to back up. It's a completely different thing to backup only small amounts of rarely changing data instead of terabytes of consistently changing data.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of questions, many of which already have answers here on Serverfault.

One strategy will not meet the requirements for all the software.

> i think i'll need Full- and incremental Backups....should be easy and fast to recover

then forget about incremental backups.

For mysql, the best solution is to maintain [a replicated slave](https://serverfault.com/questions/310737/downtimeless-mysql-backups-on-a-budget) which you can stop and run mysqldump against.

For the other stuff, the best solution with minimal downtime would be to have a mirrored filesystem - then when you want to backup,

- stop the mail services,
- flush the buffers,
- break the mirror,
- start up mail services
- mount the mirror elsewhere
- backup from the mirror
- unmount the mirror
- join it back into the volume group

> Further, i don't want to do much to recover everything. Let's say like a backup server which we can switch to if the production server goes down

Not sure what you mean here. If you only want to provide for hardware failures/onsite recovery and you've already got a backup machine available, then run the mysql slave there, and put the data for the other applications on a shared drive - e.g. a volume maintained via DRBD, preferably with a cluter file system running on it - like GFS or Lustre - or use a replicated filesystem like AFS.

Comment: +1 except I would not "forget about incremental backups".  Smart use of incremental backups (e.g. Weekly full, Daily incremental ; Monthly full, Weekly differential, Daily incremental) can still be recovered without too much effort/time and saves a lot of space on the backup media.

Comment: i found another solution that - i think - fits my needs better: using linux-ha with heartbeat, openais and pacemaker. thanks for your answer !